# Supervision strategy of a separately started process

Tags: process, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

Consider the following module-based Supervisor:

```
defmodule MyApp.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(init_arg) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(_init_arg) do
    Supervisor.init([Worker], strategy: :rest_for_one)
  end
end
```

After the Supervisor has been started, if another process is [started](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.7/Supervisor.html#start_child/2) using :

```
Supervisor.start_child(MyApp.Supervisor, SomeOtherWorker)
```

will it be included in the defined `:strategy`?

Answer (score 0):

The separately started process appears to be included in the defined `:strategy`, when tested locally:

```
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Interactive Elixir (1.15.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Supervisor.which_children(SupervisorDemo.Supervisor)
[{Worker, #PID<0.140.0>, :worker, [Worker]}]

iex(2)> Supervisor.start_child(SupervisorDemo.Supervisor, SomeOtherWorker)
{:ok, #PID<0.156.0>}

iex(3)> Supervisor.which_children(SupervisorDemo.Supervisor)
[
  {SomeOtherWorker, #PID<0.156.0>, :worker, [SomeOtherWorker]},
  {Worker, #PID<0.140.0>, :worker, [Worker]}

iex(4)> GenServer.stop(Worker)
:ok

iex(5)> Supervisor.which_children(SupervisorDemo.Supervisor)
[
  {SomeOtherWorker, #PID<0.158.0>, :worker, [SomeOtherWorker]},
  {Worker, #PID<0.157.0>, :worker, [Worker]}
]
```

Comment: This works when both GenServers have `restart: :permanent`. If both have `restart: :transient` the Worker process is stopped after `GenServer.stop(Worker)` is called, but the SomeOtherWorker process is not stopped or restarted.